# Efficient generation of a von Mises-Fisher distribution

Tags: algorithms, random

The [von Mises-Fisher distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution) is a probability distribution on the ($p-1$)-sphere.
I'm interested in the efficient generation of this distribution for a relatively high dimension ($1000$ or greater) for application in a search step in a meta-heuristic.

¿Is there a numerical algorithm to efficiently generate such a distribution?

I'll be sampling a lot of vectors, so I'm more interested in efficiency that exactitude. I could use some approximation, or any other easily generated distribution that allows me to select a direction with a mean and a concentration parameter, similar to von Mises-Fisher.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/03610919408813161)?

Comment: Seems what I'm looking for but sadly I'm on a forbidden country (Cuba) and almost never (like zero-probability) have access to online paying services. Thanks for the link anyway, you have my upvote.